# Which SEC forms do public companies file when they issue new bonds?

Tags: united-states, bonds, sec, electronic-filing, corporate-bonds

Which SEC forms do public companies file on EDGAR when they issue new bonds?

Judging by [Coca Cola Co](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0000021344&owner=include&count=40) and [Apple Inc.](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0000320193&owner=include&count=40) SEC filings, the relevant forms seem to be:

- Form 424B2, Form 424B5 — the prospectus for the bond(s).
- Form 8-A12B — if the bonds will be exchange-traded (e.g. on the NYSE) rather than traded over-the-counter (OTC).

Questions:

- What is the difference between Form 424B2 and Form 424B5?
- Did I miss any forms relevant to new bond issues?